# How to Perform Unit Conversion before Aggregating Model Fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class WeightUnit:
    KILOGRAM = "kg"
    TONNE = "tonne"
    LBS = "lbs"

    CHOICES = [
        (KILOGRAM, _("kg")),
        (TONNE, _("tonne")),
        (LBS, _("lbs")),
    ]

    TONNE_CONVERSION_FACTOR = {
        TONNE: 1,
        KILOGRAM: 0.001,
        LBS: 0.000453592,
    }


class Product(models.Model):
    weight = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_("total weight"))
    weight_unit = models.CharField(
        _("weight unit"),
        choices=WeightUnit.CHOICES,
        default=WeightUnit.TONNE,
        max_length=5,
    )
```

Each instance of the Product model can have a different `weight_unit`, and I need to create a query that aggregates the weight field of all products while converting all weights to a single, common unit (e.g., tonnes) for the aggregation.

This is the query that I tried and got `KeyError: F(weight_unit)`:

```
    conversion_expression = ExpressionWrapper(
         F('total_weight') * WeightUnit.TONNE_CONVERSION_FACTOR[F('weight_unit')],
         output_field=FloatField(),
     )

    return Products.objects.annotate(
        converted_weight=conversion_expression,
    ).aggregate(
        weight=Sum('converted_weight', default=0.0),
    )["weight"]
```

How can I achieve this using Django's queryset and database expressions?